# Can I use Spyder interface with a remote server?

Tags: anaconda, spyder

I installed `anaconda` on remote server and typed `spyder` which gave this message:

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have a script I've worked on locally. I could just `scp` it but would prefer to continue working on the script within `spyder`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder can't work in a server that doesn't have an X server installed (clearly your case) because it's a graphical application.